# If a Taylor series converges on $A=[z:r<|z-z_0|<R]$, then it converges on $[z:|z-z_0|<R]$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on Laurent's Theorem in a complex analysis text. Prior to proving Laurent's Theorem, the author states:

Theorem: Suppose that the Laurent Series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges on the annulus $A=[z: r<|z-z_0|<R]$. Then the series converges uniformly on any closed sub annulus $[z:\ s\le|z-z_o|\le t]$ where $r<s<t<R$.

Now, the Laurent series can be written as
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{-n}(z-z_0)^{-n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$$
where the first series on the right is called the principal part and the second series on the right is called the analytic part (also a Taylor's series).

Now, the author focuses on the analytic part and uses the theorem "If $\sum_{n=o}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$ has a radius of convergence $R>0$, then for each $0<r<R$, the series converges uniformly on the closed disk $[z:|z-z_0| \le r]$."

Now, my confusion. We're given that the analytic part converges on $[z:r<|z-z_0|<R]$, but why does this make the radius of convergence equal to $R$? We're not given that it converges on $[z:|z-z_0|<R]$.

So, if the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges on $[z:r<|z-z_0|<R]$, how do I formally show that it converges on $[z:|z-z_0|<R]$? Or, can you share a counterexample that shows this is not true? Thanks.

Comment: Reference topic: Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.

Answer (score 1):

If a power series $\sum a_n(z-a)^{n}$ converges for some $z$ then it converges for $|\zeta | <|z|$; in fact it converges uniformly for $|\zeta | <|z|-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$. This is one of the basic properties of power series and a proof can be found in any book on Complex Analysis.

Comment: How about sharing a proof?

Comment: Have you seen the definition of radius of convergence? We first prove that there exists $R$ such that the series converges for $|z-a| <R$ and diverges for $|z-a| >R$. This $R$ is unique and it is called the radius of convergence. $\{z: |z-a| <R\}$ is called the circle of convergence. @David

Comment: Yes, and I have proved that if $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges on $D_R=[z:|z-z_0|<R]$, then it converges uniformly for all $z\in[z:|z-z_0|\le r]$, where $0<r<R$. However, note that to perform this proof, we are given that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges on $D_R=[z:|z-z_0|<R]$. Still, what am I supposed to do when I am only given that it converges on $A=[z:r<|z-z_0|<R]$?

Comment: Suppose $|z-z_0| <r$. Let $\zeta =z_0+(R-\epsilon) (z-z_0)$. Verify that if $\epsilon$ is small enough then $r<|\zeta-z_0| <R$ (which makes the series converges at $\zeta$) and that $|z-z_0| <|\zeta -z_0|$ (so that it converges at $z$ also. @David